# GCC generated assembly

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, reverse-engineering

Why printf function causes the change of prologue?

C code_1:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
  int a = 11;
  printf("%d", a);
}
```

GCC -m32 generated one:

```
.LC0:
        .string "%d"
main:
        lea     ecx, [esp+4]           // What's purpose of this three
        and     esp, -16               // lines?
        push    DWORD PTR [ecx-4]      // 
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    ecx
        sub     esp, 20                // why sub 20?
        mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-12], 11
        sub     esp, 8
        push    DWORD PTR [ebp-12]
        push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        add     esp, 16
        mov     eax, 0
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
        leave
        lea     esp, [ecx-4]
        ret
```

C code_2:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
  int a = 11;
}
```

GCC -m32:

```
main:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 11
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

What is the purpose of first three lines added in first code?
Please, explain first assembly code, if you can.

EDIT:

64-bit mode:

```
.LC0:
        .string "%d"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 11
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

Comment: Maybe the [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/OyxeLq)-Tool can help you for your analysis.

Comment: I'm using Godbolt. This assembly is generated on Godbolt :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The insight is that the compiler keep the stack aligned at function calls.
The alignment is 16 byte.

```
lea     ecx, [esp+4]           ;Save original ESP to ECX (ESP+4 actually)
and     esp, -16               ;Align stack on 16 bytes (Lower esp)

push    DWORD PTR [ecx-4]      ;Push main return address (Stack at 16B + 4)
                               ;My guess is to aid debugging tools that expect the RA
                               ;to be at [ebp+04h]
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp               ;Prolog (Stack at 16B+8)

push    ecx                    ;Save ECX (Original stack pointer) (Stack at 16B+12)

sub     esp, 20                ;Reserve 20 bytes (Stack at 16B+0, ALIGNED AGAIN)
                               ;4 for alignment + 1x16 for a variable (variable space is
                               ;allocated in multiple of 16)

mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-12], 11 ;a = 11

sub     esp, 8                 ;Stack at 16B+8 for later alignment
push    DWORD PTR [ebp-12]     ;a
push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC0       ;"%d"     (Stack at 16B)
call    printf
add     esp, 16                ;Remove args+pad from the stack (Stack at 16B)

mov     eax, 0                 ;Return 0

mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp-4] ;Restore ECX without the need to add to esp
leave                          ;Restore EBP

lea     esp, [ecx-4]           ;Restore original ESP
ret
```

I don't know why the compiler saves `esp+4` in `ecx` instead of `esp` (`esp+4` is the address of the first parameter of `main`).

Comment: If this first three line is necessary for save information, why 64-bit code uses the same thing? (view edited post)

Comment: @J.Doe What same thing? The 64-bit code has a standard prolog.

Comment: Why 64-bit mode don't saves original ESP as in 32-bit mode?

Comment: @J.Doe Because the ABI for 64 bit imposes that at the start of a function the stack is at 16B+8, while for 32 bit this is not true for `main`. Knowing the initial state of the stack pointer let the compiler omit the `and` instruction and use instead pushes and arithmetic on `rsp`. The `and` is not reversible and thus the original state must be saved. The push/arithmetic is reversible and the original state is restored in the prolog.

Comment: sorry for my newbie questions :d :) 
what is ABI and what's mean 16B+8?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, that's the ABI, there should be links to the PDF docs (or you can Google the keywords). 16B+X means an address that is X bytes after a multiple of 16. For example 16B+8 can be 8 (16*0+8) or 24 (16*1+8) or 40 (16*2+8) and so on.

Comment: @J.Doe: links to ABI docs in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: gcc does that weird R/ECX or R10 thing when aligning the stack to 32B even in 64-bit code, when using `__m256`.  I still have no idea what that's about.  Maybe I should ask an SO question about it vs. clang's technique, since I think clang is different.